# how to extract text by style in openoffice

Tags: openoffice-writer

I have an openoffice text using different styles. I need to extract all text in one style as a text `.txt` file (but not including text marked in the other styles). How can this be achieved?

I tried to mark other styles as hidden and save as `.txt`, but the result contains all text, not only the one which is visible. If I save as `.pdf` and then cut and paste the text from I get what I need, but this seems a roundabout solution and I am certain a better one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select all text with a certain paragraph style, go to *Edit -> Find & Replace*. Expand *Other options* and check *Paragraph Styles*. Then select the style name to *Find* and press *Find All*.

[image: Find and Replace Paragraph Styles]

Now close the dialog. Copy and paste to a text editor such as Notepad (depending on your operating system). Then save the text file from the text editor.

For character styles, this will not work, so use [AltSearch](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer).

Comment: Thank you for confirming that there is no better solution. Your solution is a bit simpler than what I have used, but I wish there were a more straightforward one.